# why a fetch assoc return null in PDO PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to get the max value of a colunm in a table. I use PDO and PHP. I have created a function to do it. This function is:

```
 function maximaPartida($link){
    try{
    $consulta = $link->prepare("select MAX(idPartida) as maxId from partidas");
    $consulta->execute();
    echo $consulta->getAttribute;
    $result = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    
}catch (PDOException $e){
    $dato = "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    echo $dato;
    die();
 }  

}
```

I call to this function of this way (crewating and object and calling the specific method) but when I do that it returns NULL.

```
$partida = new Partida();
$id = $partida->maximaPartida($base->link);
$partida->idPartida = $id['maxId'];
```

$id is NULL. Why it happen? What I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not return anything. Try this:

```
function maximaPartida($link)
{
  try {
    $consulta = $link->prepare("select MAX(idPartida) as maxId from partidas");
    $consulta->execute();
    echo $consulta->getAttribute;
    $result = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    $dato = "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    echo $dato;
    die();
  }  
  // return something from this function
  return $result;
}
```

See: [Returning values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) in the manual.